# How to make JS always checks if the value is changed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**in unity, there's (void update)that is called every frame so I wanted to know if there's
something like that in Web Dev(in js)***
"because the values could change I want it to always check if it changed then changes the values"

```js
let governmentprice = parseFloat(select.value)
let weightprice = parseFloat(weight.value);
let finalprice = governmentprice + weightprice;

price.innerText += finalprice;
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
  <select class="select price" name="recieverscity" id="select">
    <option>Governorate</option>
    <option value="50" class="btn solid"> Cairo</option>
    <option value="65" class="btn solid"> Alexandria</option>
  </select>
</div>
<input type="number" placeholder="Weight of shippement (Kg)" id="weight">
<div>
</div>
<div>
  <h2 class="title" id="price">
    Price :
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: For making sure you know about changes, there is the observer/observable pattern. In web dev that's usually solved by listening for events, however, I'm not familiar with Unity3D - I suspect it's still using events but I'm not sure how you subscribe to them.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you improve your answer, read "How do I write a good question?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add an 'onchage' event on your form elements:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange
>
> The onchange property of the GlobalEventHandlers mixin is an EventHandler for processing change events.

via a listener

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
>
> The EventTarget method addEventListener() sets up a function that will be called whenever the specified event is delivered to the target. Common targets are Element, Document, and Window, but the target may be any object that supports events (such as XMLHttpRequest).

possible example

```js
let weight = document.querySelector('#weight');
let myselect = document.querySelector('#select')

myselect.addEventListener('change', update);
weight.addEventListener('change', update);

function update() {
  let governmentprice = parseFloat(myselect.value);
  let weightprice = parseFloat(weight.value);
  let finalprice = governmentprice + weightprice;
  price.innerText = 'Price :' + finalprice
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <select class="select price" name="recieverscity" id="select">

      <option value="0">Governorate</option>
      <option value="50" class="btn solid"> Cairo</option>
      <option value="65" class="btn solid"> Alexandria</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Weight of shippement (Kg)" id="weight">
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title" id="price">
      Price :
    </h2>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="price.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a EventListener to do that.

```
HTMLInputElementObject.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
    // Code you want to execute
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In a normal web page you would use [eventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Note I use [delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) to have one eventlistener for all.

You can narrow the delegation if you wrap the input fields in a container, then use the container instead of document where I use document.addEventListener

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // now the script can live in the head of the page
  const select = document.getElementById("select"),
    weight = document.getElementById("weight"),
    price = document.getElementById("price");
  document.addEventListener("input", function() {
    const governmentprice = +select.value;
    const weightprice = +weight.value;
    const finalprice = governmentprice + weightprice;
    price.innerText = finalprice;
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
  <select class="select price" name="recieverscity" id="select">
    <option value="">Governorate</option>
    <option value="50" class="btn solid"> Cairo</option>
    <option value="65" class="btn solid"> Alexandria</option>
  </select>
</div>
<input type="number" placeholder="Weight of shipment (kg)" id="weight">
<div>
</div>
<div>
  <h2 class="title">
    Price : <span id="price"></span>
  </h2>
</div>
```